# NHibernate + concurrent edits: How to get notified of changes?

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, notifications

I'm looking into using NHibernate to handle the persistence layer in my business application. Right now, I'm wondering how to handle concurrent edits/updates in NHibernate, or more specifically, how to let multiple, distributed instances of my application know that one user changed a given dataset.

I'm *not* looking for versioning, i.e. consistency in the face of concurrent edits - I know NHibernate supports optimistic/pessimistic concurrency, and I currently use optimistic concurrency via  and handling the `StateStateException`.

I just want to know: Given that user A changes a row in the dataset, how to let user B know that a change occured so that the dataset can be reloaded? Right now, I'm lazy loading a large list of customers into a grid using NHibernate. Now, if a new customer is added, I'd like to add it to the grid without reloading the whole data again - the application's first concern is performance.

Also, will NHibernate gracefully handle changes to existing rows? Will it somehow detect changes in the underlying database and update the in-memory .NET objects so that accessing their properties will yield the updated values?

I thought about using an additional table, saving the IDs of updated objects along with a timestamp to refresh items myself, but if NHinbernate offers something of it's own, that would be a much bett choice, obviously...

Answer (score 3):

You need database-level notifications/events for this. That is, the database engine has to provide notifications. For example, [SQL Server has this feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx).  NHibernate runs on the application, so all it could *potentially* do *by itself* is polling the database for changes (your idea of using an additional table looks like polling), and we all know that's not good. NHibernate's [SysCache2](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2) takes advantage of SqlCacheDependencies to invalidate cache entries when the database raises a notification, but I'm not aware that it can raise any events to be consumed by the app itself (which wouldn't be useful anyway, since 2nd-level caches don't work with whole entities).

Another possible way to implement this would be having a NHibernate event listener place a broadcast message on a bus after any updates, then each application instance would receive this message and re-fetch from database accordingly.

Comment: As per Mauricio's second suggestion, you could set up a NHibernate interceptor that drops a note into something like a System.Messaging.MessageQueue whenever an insert or update occurs on a class that you care about.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve some similar issues on my current SQLite Fluent NHibernate project.

For detecting database updates, I used a **System.IO.FileSystemWatcher**.  See the sample code  [in my answer to my own, similar, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303843/can-nhibernate-detect-when-another-program-has-written-new-data-to-a-shared-sqlit).  Also, take a look at another answer to the same question, which suggested using **NHibernate Interceptors**.

I also lazy load my DB into a grid.  Whenever the FileSystemWatcher detects the DB has been updated, I call the following **Criteria Query**, and add the new records that it returns to the BindingList that is the DataSource for my grid.  (I just save the highest ID of the new records in a private variable)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return list of measurements with Id fields higher than id parameter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IList<T> GetMeasurementsNewerThan(int id)
    {
        var session = GetMainSession();

        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var newestMeasurements =
                session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T))
                       .Add(Expression.Gt("Id", id))
                       .List<T>();

            transaction.Commit();

            return newestMeasurements;
        }
    }
```